# Set active scheme button not showing up in Xcode 6.4(6E35b)

Tags: xcode, macos, ide

I recently upgrade my OS to 10.11 GM. One issue I have noticed is that in Xcode I no longer have the Set Active Scheme button. I'm not sure if this is because I updating my OS or if this is just some setting I don't have turned on. It was there before I updated, so I'm guessing the update had something to do with it. Here is a photo to show you what I'm seeing, or rather not seeing.[image]. I wouldn't think that just because I update my OS I would be forced to update Xcode.

Comment: Is the menu item Product > Scheme available?

Comment: Yes it is. As well as edit | new | manage

Comment: I have the same issue. I noticed that the scheme option appears again if you make the window wider.

Comment: I'm didn't show up when I resized the window. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @icekomo Have you solved this bug...I am also facing this weired situration..

Comment: @ RahulMishra, No I ended up upgrading to Xcode 7, but the issue was still there before I upgrade.